# problem with nomenclature while uploading to Scholarone manuscript?

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I am uploading the manuscript to Scholrone manuscript. All things are running properly but not printing nomenclature part and not showing any error. I have run the same manuscript with Texmaker it is showing.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I didn't understand your problem. What does it have to do with LaTeX?

Comment: I am uploading my paper to the Scholrone manuscript platform (https://mc.manuscriptcentral.com/JMES) for submission. But the nomenclature is not printed.

Comment: It seems to me it's a problem with this publisher, have you contacted him?